# Jetpack compose snackbar not displayed at bottom of screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout, android-compose-layout

I tried below code and I observe snackbar is not displayed at bottom of screen.
My task is to display snackbar on click of button.
I wrote code related to display button in a column in function DisplaySnackBarOnClik()
The code to display snackbar is written in MySnackBar().
Can anyone help me to display snackbar in the bottom of the screen by observing the below code:

```
@Composable 
fun DisplaySnackBarOnClik() {

    var canShowSnackBar by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {


Button(
              onClick = { canShowSnackBar = ! canShowSnackBar },
              modifier = modifier,
              enabled = isEnabled,
              elevation =  ButtonDefaults.elevation(
                       defaultElevation = 10.dp,
                       pressedElevation = 15.dp,
                       disabledElevation = 0.dp
             ),
             colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
             backgroundColor = colorResource(R.color.cgux_primary_700),
             contentColor = colorResource(R.color.white)
        )
            ) {
        Text(text = "Show Snack Bar")
    }

 if (canShowSnackBar) {
            MySnackbar("Hello, Snackbar!", "Dismiss")
        }

}


@Composable fun MySnackbar(
    message: String, actionLabel: String, duration: SnackbarDuration = SnackbarDuration.Short
) {
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }

    LaunchedEffect(snackbarHostState) {
        snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(message, actionLabel, duration = duration)
    }
    Box(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
    ) {
        SnackbarHost(
            hostState = snackbarHostState
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It happens because the `Box` with the `SnackbarHost` is inside the `Column` with the `verticalScroll`.

You have to move the `Box` outside the scrollable column.

```
Column() {

    var canShowSnackBar by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Button()
    }

    if (canShowSnackBar) {
        MySnackbar("Hello, Snackbar!", "Dismiss")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your contents inside Box like this. its basic structure to follow

```
Box {
   Column {
      Button()
    }
    MySnackbar()
}
```

and most important you can remove the box from your the `MySnackbar` composable.

**Detail Answer**

```
@Composable
fun DisplaySnackBarOnClik() {
    var canShowSnackBar by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    Box(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter,
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .fillMaxWidth().padding(bottom = 60.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            Button(
                onClick = { canShowSnackBar = !canShowSnackBar },
                enabled = true,
                elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(
                    defaultElevation = 10.dp,
                    pressedElevation = 15.dp,
                    disabledElevation = 0.dp,
                ),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    backgroundColor = colorResource(R.color.purple_200),
                    contentColor = colorResource(R.color.white),
                ),
            ) {
                Text(text = "Show Snack Bar")
            }
        }
        if (canShowSnackBar) {
            MySnackbar("Hello, Snackbar!", "Dismiss")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MySnackbar(
    message: String,
    actionLabel: String,
    duration: SnackbarDuration = SnackbarDuration.Short,
) {
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }

    LaunchedEffect(snackbarHostState) {
        snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(message, actionLabel, duration = duration)
    }

    SnackbarHost(
        hostState = snackbarHostState,
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have added a bottom padding too for making it more cleaner `.padding(bottom = 60.dp),`